# Searching through many excel files in same folder (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

**This is what I want to accomplish:**

I have a worksheet in excel with about 100 product IDs as well as the products' corresponding price and supplier (let's call that worksheet_1).  I would like the price and supplier to be automatically updated every time a purchase order is placed into a folder for that product. Each purchase order is an excel file with information including the product ID, supplier, price and date.

**Here is the general logic:**

One by one, the program will read each product ID from worksheet_1 using a while loop.  I will then have the program search for the product ID in every purchase order in the folder mentioned previously.  This is the part I am most unsure about, because the number of files in the folder will be variable (as purchase orders are added regularly) and most purchase orders in the folder will be within subfolders.  Anyway, for each instance of the product ID found in a purchase order; the date, supplier and price will be sent to an SQL database. The price and supplier that correspond to the most recent date will then be put back into the original excel worksheet_1.

First and foremost I would like to know how to read all the excel files from the same folder (but different subfolders) so that I can search for a particular product ID.  I think once I get that piece I can figure the rest out, but let me know if something is wrong with my logic or if there is an easier way.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You'll get down votes for any questions asking how to do something without showing your code or what you've tried yourself. People aren't keen on designing your solutions for you. That being said, to search a directory and its subfolders, try Directory.GetFiles - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I'll make sure to include what I have tried in future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search a directory and its subfolders, try Directory.GetFiles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)

foreach (string fil in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.xls"))
{
  //do some stuff with your .xls files
}
```